# Drawing an Icosphere using VBO

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to draw an icosphere using VBO and `glDrawArrays`. After each subdivision, when the depth reaches 0, I add 3 new vertices to a vector. Finally in `Render()` I call `glDrawArrays(enum mode, 0, vector.size)` but the result looks weird. I think that this is the result of not specifying the sphere indices properly. Firstly I used `glDrawElements` but just about 1/4 of the sphere was drawn on screen, then I changed to use `glDrawArrays` and got the result as below.

Could someone help to show where I get wrong please?

there are lines which connect 2 opposite points

[image: there are lines which connect 2 opposite points]

This is the code to generate the vertices:

```
int numsToDraw, numberOfVerices = 0;;

vector<GLfloat> vertices;
vector<GLfloat> normals;
vector<GLfloat> texture;
vector<GLuint> indices;

void normalize3f(float v[3]){
    GLfloat d = sqrtf(v[0]*v[0] + v[1]*v[1] + v[2]*v[2]);
    if (d == 0.0f){
        fprintf(stderr, "Zero length vector. \n");
        return;
    }
    v[0] /= d;
    v[1] /= d;
    v[2] /= d;
}

void addVertices(GLfloat v[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        vertices.push_back(v[i]);
    }
}

void subdivide(GLfloat v1[], GLfloat v2[], GLfloat v3[], int depth){
    GLfloat v12[3], v23[3], v31[3];

    if (depth == 0){
        addVertices(v1);
        addVertices(v2);
        addVertices(v3);
        //indices.push_back(numberOfVerices);
        //numberOfVerices++;
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        v12[i] = v1[i]+v2[i];
        v23[i] = v2[i]+v3[i];
        v31[i] = v3[i]+v1[i];
    }

    normalize3f(v12);
    normalize3f(v23);
    normalize3f(v31);
    subdivide(v1, v12, v31, depth-1);
    subdivide(v2, v23, v12, depth-1);
    subdivide(v3, v31, v23, depth-1);
    subdivide(v12, v23, v31, depth-1);
}

void drawSphere(int depth){
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        subdivide(icosahedron[icoindices[i][0]],
                  icosahedron[icoindices[i][1]],
                  icosahedron[icoindices[i][2]], depth);
    }
}
```

This is what I have in setup VBOs:

```
drawSphere(1);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vboVertex);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertex);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vboTexture);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboTexture);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), &texture[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vboIndex);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIndex);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    numsToDraw = indices.size();
```

This is my render method:

```
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);/* Make our background black */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART);
    glPrimitiveRestartIndex(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART_FIXED_INDEX);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIndex);

    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_test[0]);
    glUniform1i(textureLocation, 0);
    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(50.0f, 5.0f / 3.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);
        glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
            glm::vec3(0, 5, 2),
            glm::vec3(0, 0, 0),
            glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)
        );

        /* Animations */
        GLfloat angle = (GLfloat) (i);
        View = glm::translate(View, glm::vec3(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        View = glm::rotate(View, angle * 0.5f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
        /* ******* */

        glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model;

        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mvpMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP));
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, vertices.size());
    //glDrawElements(GL_LINE_LOOP, numsToDraw, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
    glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertices you produce are not compatible with the primitive you use for the draw call here:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, vertices.size());
```

`GL_LINE_LOOP` renders a connected set of lines through all of your vertices. But when you produce your vertices, you create 3 vertices per triangle:

```
addVertices(v1);
addVertices(v2);
addVertices(v3);
```

Therefore, when rendering with `GL_LINE_LOOP`, a line will be drawn from the last vertex of each triangle to the first vertex of the next triangle, while no line will be drawn between `v2` and `v3`. Looking at just two triangles with vertices `v1`, `v2`, `v3` and `v1'`, `v2'`, `v3'`, the line segments drawn will be:

```
v1  v2
v2  v3
v3  v1'
v1' v2'
v2' v3'
```

The line segment between `v3` and `v1'` corresponds to the extra lines you see. What you really want is:

```
v1  v2
v2  v3
v3  v1
v1' v2'
v2' v3'
v3' v1'
```

The most direct way to correct this is to use `GL_TRIANGLES` as the primitive type, since that directly matches the vertices you produced:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGES, 0, vertices.size());
```

This renders a solid sphere, though, while you appear to be after a wireframe sphere. You can choose to draw in wireframe mode by making this call *before* the draw call:

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
```

Another option is that you produce your vertices to draw separate line segments:

```
addVertices(v1);
addVertices(v2);

addVertices(v2);
addVertices(v3);

addVertices(v3);
addVertices(v1);
```

This matches the desired vertex sequence above. Then you can draw this with:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, vertices.size());
```

Be careful when you type the enum values for these solutions. The last argument to `glPolygonMode()` is `GL_LINE` in the first option, and the first argument to `glDrawArrays()` is `GL_LINES` in the second option. They look very similar, but are different values.